# Setting up PlaceAutocompleteFragment filter to only show results from a specific administrative_area_level_2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Trying to set up an AutocompleteFilter with a PlaceAutocompleteFragment to only show results from a google defined administrative_area_level_2. Here are its geocode results [JSON](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=cuddalore%20district) / [XML](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?&address=cuddalore%20district)

Right now I have this setup:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setCountry("IN")
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS)
            .build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

which returns all regions in India which I do not want. If there is someway to restrict by place_id or the name of the administrative_area_level_2 that would be nice.

Edit: I'm using setBoundsBias() which is not perfect but kinda works. Still looking for an answer

```
autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(11.148462, 78.8748019),
            new LatLng(11.8978939, 79.812782)));
```

Comment: There is no filters for admin areas, so the bound bias is the only workaround. Probably you are interested in the following feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067

Comment: @xomena Thanks for you answer! Good to know.